# How does an electromagnetic field shield radiation?

Tags: electromagnetism

***HOW*** does an electromagnetic field shield radiation?

Can someone please explain this at a molecular level, in thorough detail?

If you need some context, here is a link to an article describing electromagnetic radiation shielding for a Martian Base: http://article.sciencepublishinggroup.com/pdf/10.11648.j.ajae.20180502.13.pdf

Thanks.

Comment: the article you link is talking about a magnetic field, not an electromagenic one , which is defined from infrared to gamma ray radiation.

Answer (score 1):

A magnetic field can shield against radiation consisting of charged particles like electrons, protons, or ions; but it cannot shield against uncharged particles like gamma rays or neutrons.

The shielding mechanism is simple: when a charged particle moves through a magnetic field, it experiences a force directed at right angles to its direction of motion and the magnetic field direction.  That forces its trajectory to curve.  Positively charged particles curve one way, negatively charged particles curve the other way.

Comment: What about the magnetic moment of the neutron?

Comment: A uniform magnetic field can apply a torque to a magnetic dipole (e.g., a neutron), but not a net force.  A rapidly diverging field (see the Stern-Gerlach experiment) can apply a net force on a dipole, but the direction of the force depends on the orientation of the dipole: flip the dipole and the force direction reverses.  In the proposed magnetic shield, neutrons would be unaffected for all practical purposes.

Comment: What causes the particles to move different ways?

Comment: You're asking what causes posituve gharges to move one way and negative gharges to move the other way?  Ultimately, we do not know.  Physics seeks the simplest, most compact representations of observed facts and relationships - like Maxwell's equations, but does not explain *why* Maxwell's equations are true.

Answer (score 0):

Of course S. McGrew is correct, but you are asking about a thorough description at the molecular level (more like the QM level I believe). To do this, I would like to add:

1. the magnetic shielding field is described according to our currently accepted theory, the Standard Model, together with QM, by using virtual particles called virtual photons
2. these virtual particles are not real particles, not real photons, but just a mathematical model of describing the phenomena called EM field
3. In our currently accepted models, the EM interaction between the field and the (charged) particles like protons, electrons, ions is mediated by these virtual particles. Now in reality on the QM level, we do not know what is actually mediating or how it is mediating, we just have a mathematical model, using virtual photons, that describe the experimental data best.
4. As the other answer describes, the charged particles that are interacting with the EM field, are deflected, their trajectory is altered by the EM field itself. In reality we do not know how the EM field is interacting with the charged particles, but we just describe the interaction as virtual particles mediating the EM force of the field to the charged particles flying towards the field. As the charged particles start to interact via virtual photons, their trajectory gets altered to avoid the object being shielded.